# change the base href in javascript:openwindow

Tags: javascript

I have link like that in content i get from remore site with file get content

```
javascript:openwindow("http://www.remotesite.com/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=170119&tid=414745&channel=0&tmpl=component&layout=popup","730","770")
```

i want to change http://www.remotesite. com to mysite. com.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

Comment: @jeffman i dont understand that can u help explain it

Comment: Javascript doesn't have an `openwindow()` function. Do you mean `window.open()`?

Comment: @Barmar i really dont know that but the link is as the example in the question how can i change the base href in it

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can change the `href` attribute:

```
var link = document.getElementById('linkid');
link.href = link.href.replace('http://www.remotesite.com', 'http://mysite.com');
```

Comment: what should be the link id ? here is the source code i get from remote site how as u can see there is no linkid <td><a href="javascript:openWindow(%22http://www.drakulastream.eu/index1.php?option=com_lsh&amp;view=lsh&amp;event_id=170116&amp;tv_id=851&amp;tid=35229&amp;channel=0&amp;tmpl=component&amp;layout=popup&amp;Itemid=335%22,%22740%22,%22820%22)">Link#1</a>  (640x360) </td>

Comment: You need to add an `id="something"` attribute to the link, so you can reference it with `getElementById('something')`.

Comment: i have no access to add that id as i get the source code as is from remote site

Comment: Then you need to use DOM traversal functions to get to the anchor node and modify it. Since I don't know the structure of the code, I can't tell you precisely what that should be.

Comment: You could use `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` to list all the links, and iterate through this looking for one with the `href` that you want to change.

Comment: Good, that should provide the operations you need to do this. I'm not very familiar with it, but the general idea should be similar to what I did with Javascript.